# F# how to pass a function variable to a member function

Tags: f#

Given a type (Candidate) which has muiltiple fields one may score (here one concrete example with _scoreXXX) and calculate the total percentage score:

```
type ScorableCandidate() =
    let mutable _scoreXXX: int  =  0 ;
    let mutable _percentXXX: float = 0. ;

    member this.scoreXXX
        with get() = _scoreXXX
        and  set(v) =
            _scoreXXX<- v
            propertyChanged.Trigger(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("scoreXXX"))

    member this.percentXXX
        with get() = _percentXXX
        and  set(v) =
            _percentXXX <- v
            propertyChanged.Trigger(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("percentXXX"))
```

I would like to absctract the calculation of the percentages so I don't need to redefine the function everytime.  Unfortunately I am lost on how to do this with member functions.  The template  of the code I am abstracting looks is:

```
let scoreXXXs () =
     let totalXXXScore  = List.fold (fun acc (candidate: ScorableCandidate) -> acc + candidate.scoreXXXs) 0 brokers

     let score (candidate: ScorableCandidate) =
                 candidate.percentXXXs <- (float candidate.scoreXXXs) / float totalXXXScore   * 100.

     if totalXXXScore  > 0 then
                List.iter score <| brokers
```

I guess I would like to be able to define the function as "score" and pass in the aapropriate member accessors.  Such that i could write

```
    score XXX  // where xxx is some property in the class that needs to be scored
    score YYY  // where yyy is some property in the class that needs to be scored
```

One thought I had was passing in functions to get access, and that is easy enough to do for the getter but I can't seem to figure out the setter.  I realize I could defer to reflection for this - but I feel that might not be the best (f#) way... AT this point I am at:

```
    let scoreField (accessF : (ScorableCandidate -> int)) (setF : (float -> unit)) =
        let totalScore = List.fold (fun acc (candidate: ScorableCandidate) -> acc + accessF candidate) 0 brokers

        let score (candidate: ScorableCandidate) =
            setF <| (accessF candidate |> float) / float totalScore  * 100.

        if totalScore > 0 then
            List.iter score <| brokers

    scoreField (fun c -> c.scoreXXX) (fun f -> ())
```

But I don't know how (or if it is possible) to represent the setter as a lambda function on the type (where maybe I can pass the instace as paraneter to lambda function and invoke it somehow).

Thoughts?  Thanks ahead.

Update Found this approach (thoughts):
http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2009/10/17/52-dynamic-lookup-operator-aka-duck-typing-in-fsharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your settor is missing the object you're going to set the field on. So the type of `setF` should be:

```
setF : (ScorableCandidate -> float -> unit)
```

so then you'd use it like:

```
let score (candidate: ScorableCandidate) =
    (setF candidate) <| (accessF candidate |> float) / float totalScore  * 100.
```

and call your `scoreField` thus:

```
scoreField (fun c -> c.scoreXXX) (fun c f -> c.percentXXX <- f)
```

Comment: choosing this solution - because i am only developing a prototype, and this worked.  I think they are all valid approaches, and as Tomas mentioned a redesign of the object layer might be a better plan, but I am constrained by an existing RPC layer that prevents that on my end.  Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand it correctly, you need to store several scores (for various different things) in a single candidate and then perform calculations over these scores.

In that case, I would consider making `Score` a separate type that would be used by the candidate - you can then easily add multiple scores. If you need to expose score & percent as direct properties of candidate & notify using `IPropertyChange`, then you should be able to write something like this:

```
/// Takes a name of this score item (e.g. XXX) and a 
/// function to trigger the property changed event
type Score(name:string, triggerChanged) = 
  let mutable score = 0
  let mutable percent = 0.0
  member x.Score 
    with get() = score 
    and set(v) = 
      score <- v
      triggerChanged("Score" + name)
  member x.Percent 
    with get() = percent 
    and set(v) = 
      percent <- v
      triggerChanged("Percent" + name)
```

Now you can simply use the `Score` object as many times you need in the candidate (because we also want to expose direct properties, there is some boilerplate, but it should be reasonable amount):

```
type ScorableCandidate() as this = 
  // Create trigger function & pass it to Score objects
  let trigger n = propertyChanged.Trigger(this, n)
  let infoXxx = new Score("Xxx", trigger)
  member this.InfoXxx = scoreXxx             // Exposes the whole Score object
  member this.ScoreXxx = scoreXxx.Score      // & individual...
  member this.PercentXxx = scoreXxx.Percent  // ...properties
```

Now, your parameterized function can simply take a function that takes `ScorableCandidate` and returns a `Score` object:

```
let scores f =     
  let totalScore  = List.fold (fun acc (candidate: ScorableCandidate) -> 
    let so = f candidate // Get 'Score' object
    acc + so.Score) 0 brokers     
 let score (candidate: ScorableCandidate) =     
   let so = f candidate // Get 'Score' object
   so.Percent <- (float so.Score) / float totalScore * 100.0
 if totalScore > 0 then     
   List.iter score <| brokers
```

Example call would be simply:

```
scores (fun (c:ScorableCandidate) -> c.InfoXxx)
```

This makes the call to the `scores` function as easy as it can get and it is also scalable solution that makes it easy to add other calculations to the `Score` object. The disadvantage (e.g. when compared with Pavel's straightforward solution) is that there is a bit more work with designing the `Score` type (however, declaring new scores in `ScorableCandidate` is then arguably easier if you only need to expose readable property directly in the class - which I think should be enough).

Answer (score 0):

To make the API simpler, you might want to consider one of the following options:

1. Use reflection.  Then you could do `scoreField "XXX"`, and your method could explicitly translate "XXX" into `MethodInfo`s for your `get_scoreXXX` and `set_percentXXX` methods.  This has the disadvantage that it doesn't check the method names at compile time and it has the performance penalty that comes along with reflection.
2. Use quotations.  Then you could do `scoreField <@ fun c -> c.scoreXXX, c.percentXXX @>`.  This would otherwise work similarly to the reflection example, except that you'd have a bit more compile-time checking.
3. Create a type which represents score/percent combinations, and create properties of that type rather than separate properties for each.  Your `ScorePercent` class could have getters and setters for the score and percent (and raise its own change notifications).  Then, you could do `scoreField (fun c -> c.XXX)`, where the `XXX` member is of type `ScorePercent`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I took a while to decide how to phrase the question, my applogies if I was misleading. I want to be able to parametize this so that scoreXXX is just one of the options - that the logic there (for scoring) can be spread run on multiple properties of the class without having to code for it specifically. scoreXXX or scoreYYY or scoreZZZ or scoreXYZ etc are all different memebers I may want to run this on...

Comment: @akaphenom - I've edited my answer to give you some other options.

Comment: Thank you.  What would be the advantages of using Quotations versus the solution Pavel Minaev provided?

Comment: @akaphenom - Just slightly less typing.

Comment: @akaphenom: it is somewhat shorter as written, though it gave me an idea of how to rewrite my own answer :)

Comment: This problem seems like it should be abstracted further as suggested in #3 about.  Maybe using a discriminated union and a composite pattern.

Comment: I have implemented Pavels recommendation, as I am only working on a prototype.  BUT I feel like it should be able to be abstracted more...  Pavel what were your thoughts?

Comment: @akaphenom: the "abstract away concept of property in its own type" (as elaborated in Tomas's answer) is, IMO, the cleanest approach here. Mine is more of a "quick and dirty" one. Which to go with depends on how many such properties you have, and how many functions similar to `scoreField`. If it's more than a few, I'd go with his answer.